# I want to enable text box on image click in asp using java script

Tags: asp.net

I want to enable text box on image click in asp using java script initially my text box is disable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added no markup to your question so i am assuming an `Image` and writing an example of how to disable/enable with `Javascript`

```
<html>
<body>
    // Image
    <img src="\URL" onClick="EnableTxt()" />
    <script>
    // Javascript Function
       function EnableTxt() {
            document.getElementById( '<%=txtBox.ClientID%>' ).disabled = 'false';
       }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks mate but i have so many text box near about 23 and i have to do in one function??

Comment: Pass `EnableTxt(this)`